# Vote to close? Why doesn't this question follow the faq?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question, vote-to-close

I recently asked: 
[WPA2 audit tool](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36413/wpa2-audit-tool-as-of-2013)

It's been voted to close. Could someone suggest where my question goes outside the faq, and how to amend the question so as to spare it from closure?

The question is not intended to invite argument or open-ended discussion. I am looking for some field-tested solutions that actually work, before investing into the hardware. For example, the answer might be like, "running OS X with 2 Nvidia/ATI cards, aircrack-ng is very popular and reliable. Here's a link"

The other question is a simple yes/no question, "is pyrit dead?"

Answer (score 2):

Looking at it, I can see two problems.

1. You haven't asked 'Is Pyrit dead'. Instead you asked if it was the preferred solution. Which is an opinion question.
2. 'Is pyrit dead' is not suitable here. The answer will be best found by looking at the pyrit site for updates. Any answer posted here could be out of date tomorrow

If you edit it to ask for a working config it could be reopened - even that is marginal though, as different users may have different configs, and lists of answers aren't useful here.

Comment: Also, "Is pyrit the preferred WPA2 auditor of the ethical hacker community as of 2013?" <- too localized; point-in-time.

Answer (score 1):

“Is Pyrit dead” is best answered by looking up a primary source of information about the project. “What tool should I use” is borderline between “what's the best tool” (which is a matter of opinion) and “how do I accomplish the task” (which is a good question). The point is that answers should be “here's how you can do this: <explanation>” and not “I like tool X”.

I've edited the question, hopefully tipping it into objectively-answerable territory, and voted to reopen.